# Nav Search Bar that Searches Users in Database

Tags: ruby-on-rails, twitter-bootstrap, searchbar

I have a nav bar with a search field in it from Bootstrap. In my rails application I would like to have that search bar access Users in the database's page similar to a Facebook search bar. Can I do this with a Form tag or is there a better way? I have looked at the Sunspot gem but I don't think that it is necessary in this case, but I may be wrong.

Answer (score 0):

You can use a simple form tag on the page with ajax autocomplete, and use ElasticSearch on the backend for the search. Here's a tutorial about it: https://shellycloud.com/blog/2013/10/adding-search-and-autocomplete-to-a-rails-app-with-elasticsearch

Comment: Cool. I didnt know where to look I will check this out.

Comment: This seems to be a search bar for a particular page in an application. What I need is for the Nav Search bar that comes from Bootstrap to be able to search for users on any page of my application. Is this still useful, maybe I am missing somethiing

Comment: It doesn't matter if the search is in a particular page or inside a partial (like the header partial to be all over the pages). The concept is the same. You can check this Railscast to understand better:

http://railscasts.com/episodes/399-autocomplete-search-terms